# Symfony2.1 SonataUserBundle ResourceBundle error

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I have this problem with Symfony.

I now use SonataUserBundle and I have this error:

> The locale resource bundle could not be loaded for locale "en"
>   (uncaught exception) at
>   [...]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Locale.php
>   line 16

I have `intl` installed.

I did some research on Internet, and find I had to do

```
php data-build.php 49
```

Which gives me this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ResourceBundle' not found in [...]Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/data/build-data.php on line 97

Comment: Are you sure that the intl bundle is installed? Try to run this command: `php -i|grep intl`. What does it return?

Comment: Have you uncommended this line "extension=php_intl.dll" in your php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling or updating composer?  I know whenever I have problems with any third party vendors I'll delete my composer.lock file and update composer to generate a new one.